# View [pageTitle] not found

Tags: laravel

Hi I'm following a tutorial and I change a little bit the name of prefix into admin and the route was working before with empty content and then once I put some of the contents following the tutorial the login page title is not working here's the code

from auth-laout.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <title>@yield('pageTitle')</title>

    <!--logo-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./back/CCS_logo.png">

    <!--Bootstrap CSS-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./back/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!---Styles---->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./back/style.css">

    <!--Icon----->
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.9/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    @stack('stylesheets')
</head>
<body>
    
    

        <!-- Content Page -->
        @yield('content')
        
    
    
    <script src="./back/script.js"></script>
    @stack('scripts')
    <script src="./back/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

the login file login.blade.php

```
@extends('back.layouts.auth-layout')
@extends('pageTitle', isset($pageTitle) ? $pageTitle : 'Login')
@section('content')

this is a login page

@endsection
```

I can't seem to find what's the problem I haven't missed any tutorials

this is the error been throw Illuminate
 \ View\ FileViewFinder: 137 findInPaths
throw new InvalidArgumentException("View [{$name}] not found.");

Thank you for helping! i'm still a beginner learning this laravel framework

find solution on internet but i can't seem to solve it

Answer (score 1):

View [pageTitle] not found

Use this:

```
@section('title') {{''Login''}} @endsection
```